# Jquery Error after updating theme version on wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I receive error when I insert this code to my website. This code works well before I update my theme version.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".text-sep").text("|");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you tell us what is the error displaying to you in your site.

Comment: I want to change this character "/" to this "|"

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. It may help you.

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $(".text-sep").html(function() {
    return $(this).html().replace("|", "/");
 });

});
```